# Raspivid fails only when used with gstreamer?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, pi-zero, raspivid, gstreamer

I have a Pi Zero running Raspbian Jessie and a pi camera. I've installed gstreamer with:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0
```

If I run:

```
raspivid -w 1280 -h 720 -v -fps 10 -b 500000 -t 0 -o - | \ 
gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 \
! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=raspberrypi.local port=5000
```

I get

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPServerSink:tcpserversink0: current-port = 5000
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
```

However, there's nothing wrong with my camera. The following works perfectly and produces a normal jpeg:

```
$ raspistill -v -o test.jpg

raspistill Camera App v1.3.8

Width 3280, Height 2464, quality 85, filename test.jpg
Time delay 5000, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
Camera component done
Encoder component done
Starting component connection stage
Connecting camera preview port to video render.
Connecting camera stills port to encoder input port
Opening output file test.jpg
Enabling encoder output port
Starting capture -1
Finished capture -1
Closing down
Close down completed, all components disconnected, disabled and destroyed
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you considered that the Pi Zero may not be able to keep up with the load and it is not pushing the image to the streaming buffer fast enough to prevent a time out?

Comment: Not really, as my CPU usage is 5%

Comment: also there are other documents of gstreamer being run on the Pi Zero the same way i'm trying: http://referencedesigner.com/blog/using-gstreamer-with-raspberry-pi-0/6252/